# Multithread program help in java

Tags: multithreading

I need help on writing multithread program to process files, i will have set of file names appended with group number and sequence.  my requirement is each thread should dedicate to process one group set of files in sequence order.

Ex:

File format :   GroupNumber_Sequence_File.txt

- Group 1 with sequence 1,2,3 should process by thread 1

  1_1_FIlE.txt

  1_2_FILE.txt

  1_3_File.txt
- Group 2 with sequence 1,2,3 should process by thread 2

  2_1_FILE.txt

  2_2_FILE.txt

  2_3_File.txt
- Group 3 with sequence 1,2,3 should process by thread 3

  3_1_FIlE.txt

  3_2_FILE.txt

  3_3_File.txt

Comment: please show us code you've already written that attempts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a class that implements Runnable. This class will have a constructor That accepts the group Id (like 1,2....) and the list of files which have that group ID. Then you just create new instances of the class and Start the thread

For listing the files, you can use any of the methods in File class. (I'm not sure about the method name)
Then once you get the list of files, you can write a method that will check for the pattern ie check whether the filename contains 1_1 or 1_2 ....  and accordingly populate